# I’m also used while playing games

Tags: riddle

> I have many famous names,
>
> I’m also used while playing games.
>
> Where there’s money I may abound,
>
> If there’s none I won’t be found.
>
> I can range from big to small,
>
> But go too big, and you may fall.

What am I?

**Hint:**

> It is something tangible.

Comment: I was going to say "imagination" before the hint.

Comment: Similarly I was writing up an answer of "lie" until I checked that.

Comment: I was gonna say 'Tax', I think it freaking fits! But no, not anymore

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad since there are currently 7 upvoted answers, none of which seems to have been accepted.  Please consider adding more details to the puzzle itself (not hints).

Comment: Also voting to close, but I will retract my close vote if you [edit] the question to add a few lines to the riddle and narrow its scope a bit.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe

> A wager

I have many famous names:

> [image: other names]

I'm also used while playing games:

> You may wager that someone is going to win

Where there's money I may abound:

> You use money to make wagers

If there's none I won't be found:

> If you take money to be anything of value, You can't wager without it

I can range from big to small:

> A big wager, a small wager

But go too big and you may fall:

> If you wager too much and lose, you could fall into trouble

Comment: "You can't wager if you don't have money" -- I'll bet you a bottle of wine that's not true.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You still need money to buy the bottle of wine ;)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yeah that was the weak part of my answer.

Comment: @Lyrion I have some bottles of wine at home. I didn't buy them, they were brought by party guests.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Who still in one way or the other payed money for it. Even if you wager for things they will always have a monetary value.

Comment: In that case, "where there's money" becomes *everywhere* since pretty much anything can be given a nonzero monetary value, and that line of the riddle becomes useless. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You might be a:

> Dollar bill.

I have many famous names

> Most dollar bills have the faces of someone famous on them.

I am also used while playing games

> Monopoly uses paper money (albeit fake ones).

Where there's money I may abound,
If there's none I won't be found

> Dollar bills ARE money, so...

I can range from big to small

> Dollar bills come in a range of denominations

But go too big and you may fall

> The infamous Zimbabwe multi-trillion note (or something, I do not recall) shows that with extremely large denominations, money loses its value, and thus falls. Being a creature who needs money I suppose you fall too?

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> bank?

I have many famous names,

> There are many banks with internationally known names

I’m also used while playing games.

> Monopoly (for example) has a bank

Where there’s money I may abound,
If there’s none I won’t be found.

> Banks can only exist if there's money for them to store or loan

I can range from big to small,

> There are big banks and small local ones

But go too big, and you may fall.

> Referencing [too big to fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_big_to_fail)

Comment: You won't fall if you're "too big to fail", that's the point of that Wikipedia article. Contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my guess

> Coin

I have many famous names,

> Cent, Pence, Pfennig, etc... Lots of different names for coins in different countries

I’m also used while playing games.

> You can bet coins, some games can use coins as markers

Where there’s money I may abound,

> Coins carry a monetary value

If there’s none I won’t be found.

> If there's no money, there can't be any coins

I can range from big to small,

> Coins have a wide variety of sizes

But go too big, and you may fall.

> If you have a bunch of them they will be very heavy and could make you off-balance

Answer (score 5):

You're a

> poker chip

I have many famous names,

> referencing famous casino names?

I’m also used while playing games.

> used in gambing

Where there’s money I may abound,

> self explanatory

If there’s none I won’t be found.

> also self explanatory

I can range from big to small,

> large and small valuation

But go too big, and you may fall.

> My guess is 'going big' is referencing a large bet - bet too large and you might lose it all

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and good answer!

Answer (score 2):

Are you ...

> Alcohol?

I have many famous names

> Rum, Vodka, Gin, Whiskey, even Beer

I’m also used while playing games

> Drinking games, e.g. beer pong, King's Cup

Where there’s money I may abound,

> Can't buy alcohol without money...

If there’s none I won’t be found.

> Could be wrong here, since its just a repetition of the previous clue. Without money, you can't get alcohol.

I can range from big to small,

> Either referring to size of bottles/cans (500mL vs 1L bottles, or 355mL vs 500mL beer cans, etc) or the percentage strength of the particular alcohol (40% Vodka vs ~75% Bacardi 151, etc)

But go too big, and you may fall.

> We all know what happens when one consumes too much alcohol :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you a...

> Mouse?

I have many famous names

> Mickey Mouse, Jerry the Mouse, Speedy Gonzalez (as many others)

I’m also used while playing games

> Well you actually can use a mouse to play PC games

Where there’s money I may abound,

If there’s none I won’t be found.

> Im not sure about this but could be related to... https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(manga)

I can range from big to small

> Well, mouses have different sizes...

But go too big, and you may fall.

> Exists a place called Mouse Creek Falls